# Angular and Karma testing a service that uses $resource and returns a promise

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-resource

I am trying to develop a Unit Test using Jasmine for my AngularJS User service that relies on $resource. My test which is:

```
'use strict';

describe("User Service Test", function() {

var service;
var mockLoginUser = { email: 'hidden', password: "hidden" };

  beforeEach(module('flightlottery.userApi'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(User) {
    service = User;
  //  $scope = _$scope_;
    //http = $httpBacked;
  }));

it('should fetch login a user', function(done) {
    var testUser = function(user) {
        console.log('callback called');
      //expect(user.email).toBe(mockLoginUser.email);
      //expect(user.password).toBe(mockUser.password);
    };

    var failTest = function(error) {
      expect(error).toBeUndefined();
    };

    //http.expectPost('/users/login', mockLoginUser).respond(200,'');

    //http.expectGET('/employees/1').respond(200,mockEmployee);

    service.login(mockLoginUser)
      .$promise.then(testUser)
      .catch(failTest)
      .finally(done);

//    $scope.$apply;
    //http.flush();
});
});
```

When I run my test I get the following error.

```
Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Can anyone let me know how to accomplish this? I find it rather confusing.

Thanks!

***EDIT:
Here is my user service. I would like to test the login method.

```
angular.module('flightlottery.userApi', ['ngResource']).
factory('User', function($resource, $rootScope) {

  var current_user;

  var User = $resource('http://somesite.ca/api/users/:method/:id', {}, {
    query: {method:'GET', params: {method:'index'}, isArray:true },
    save: {method:'POST', params: {method:'save'} },
    get: {method:'GET', params: {method:'edit'} },
    phistory: {method:'GET', params: {method:'history'}, isArray:true },
    remove: {method:'DELETE', params: {method:'remove'} },
    login: {method:'POST', params: {method:'login'} },
    logout: {method:'POST', params: {method:'logout'} },
    register: {method:'POST', params: {method:'register'} }
  });


  User.setCurrentUser = function(user) {
    //var self = this;
    current_user = user;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('user:updated',user);
    //console.log(self.current_user_id);
  }

  User.getCurrentUser = function() {
    //var self = this;
    return current_user;
    //console.log(self.current_user_id);
  }

  User.registerUser = function(cb) {
    //console.log(cb);
    return User.register(cb);
  }

  User.play_history = function(cb) {
    //console.log(cb);
    return User.phistory(cb);
  }

  User.loginUser = function(cb) {
    return User.login(cb);
  }

  User.logoutUser = function(cb) {
    current_user = null;
    return User.logout(cb);
  //  return User.logout();
    ///return User.save({id: this.id},
        //angular.extend({}, this, {id:undefined}), cb);
  };

  User.prototype.update = function(cb) {
    return User.save({id: this.id},
        angular.extend({}, this, {id:undefined}), cb);
  };

  User.prototype.destroy = function(cb) {
    return User.remove({id: this.id}, cb);
  };

  return User;
});
```

Comment: ngResource testing is part of angularjs tutorial in step 13 https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying to guess what you want to accomplish, little refactoring – the results looks like this.

I'm always wonder what really we want test and what we want to prove if test pass or fail.

**Version with dependencies stubbed**

```js
angular.module('flightlottery.userApi', ['ngResource'])
  .factory('User', function($resource) {
    var User = $resource('http://somesite.ca/api/users/:method/:id', {}, {
      login: {
        method: 'POST',
        params: {
          method: 'login'
        }
      }
    });

    User.loginUser = function(cb) {
      return User.login(cb);
    }

    return User;
  })

describe("User Service Test", function() {

  var service;
  var queryDeferred;
  var mockLoginUser = {
    email: 'hidden',
    password: "hidden"
  };

  var scenarios = {
    success: function(user) {
      expect(user.email).toBe(mockLoginUser.email);
      expect(user.password).toBe(mockLoginUser.password);
    },

    fail: function(error) {
      expect(error).toBeDefined();
    }
  }

  beforeEach(module('flightlottery.userApi'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$rootScope_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  beforeEach(inject(function($q) {
    queryDeferred = $q.defer();
    mockUserLogin = {
      login: function() {
        return {
          $promise: queryDeferred.promise
        };
      }
    }

    spyOn(mockUserLogin, 'login').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(scenarios, 'success').and.callThrough();
    spyOn(scenarios, 'fail').and.callThrough();
  }))


  it('runs `success scenario` if user object is fetched', function() {
    queryDeferred.resolve(mockLoginUser)

    userLogin(mockLoginUser, scenarios);

    expect(scenarios.success).toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(scenarios.fail).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
  });

  it('runs `fail scenario` if user object is not fetched', function() {
    var reason = {
      error: 'some error'
    }
    queryDeferred.reject(reason)

    userLogin(mockLoginUser, scenarios)

    expect(scenarios.success).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    expect(scenarios.fail).toHaveBeenCalledWith(reason)
  });

  function userLogin(mockLoginUser, scenarios) {
    mockUserLogin.login(mockLoginUser)
      .$promise.then(scenarios.success)
      .catch(scenarios.fail)
      .finally();

    $rootScope.$apply();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

**Second version - injected service and $httpBackend**

> When an Angular application needs some data from a server, it calls the $http service, which sends the request to a real server using $httpBackend service. With dependency injection, it is easy to inject $httpBackend mock (which has the same API as $httpBackend) and use it to verify the requests and respond with some testing data without sending a request to a real server.

```js
angular.module('flightlottery.userApi', ['ngResource']).
factory('User', function($resource, $rootScope) {

  var User = $resource('http://somesite.ca/api/users/:method/:id', {}, {
    login: {
      method: 'POST',
      params: {
        method: 'login'
      }
    }
  });

  User.loginUser = function(cb) {
    return User.login(cb);
  }

  return User;
});


describe("User Service Test", function() {

  var $httpBackend, User;

  beforeEach(module('flightlottery.userApi'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$httpBackend_, _User_) {
    $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
    User = _User_;
  }));
  
  afterEach(function() {
     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
     $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
   });

  it('calls `POST` method to interacts with backend', function() {
    var stubUser = {
      name: 'Some name',
      password: 'somePassword'
    };
    var stubResponse = {
      login: 'someName',
      lastLogin: Date.now()
    }
    
    spyOn(User, 'login').and.callThrough();
    
    User.loginUser(stubUser).$promise.then(function(response) { // response is stubbed by second argument of repond method
      expect(response.login).toBe(stubResponse.login)
      expect(response.lastLogin).toBe(stubResponse.lastLogin)
    });
    
    expect(User.login).toHaveBeenCalledWith(stubUser)
    $httpBackend.expectPOST('http://somesite.ca/api/users/login').respond(200, stubResponse)
    $httpBackend.flush();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//safjanowski.github.io/jasmine-jsfiddle-pack/pack/jasmine-2.0.3-concated.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular-mocks.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Krzystof,

How would you use your code to test the updated service I included? My apologies for not including it in the first place. Also it does not look like your service is being passed in? Could you explain this a bit more?

Thanks!

Comment: @CamrinParnell – Take a look to new added second approach - how injected service can be tested

Comment: This is really great! It works, however I am not sure how I can get the data to check if an array of data was returned?

Comment: `$httpBackend.expect[GET|POST|PUT|DELETE].respond` as second arguments takes data that will be returned when `$httpBackend.flush()` will be called. Something new is property `$promise` - it unwraps `$resource` returned object to simle promise project - so I have access to method `then()`

Comment: How come when you do:

    User.loginUser(stubUser).$promise.then(function(data) {
      console.log(data.id);
      expect(data.email).toBe(stubResponse.email);
    });

It doesn't actually return the data from the server? The id field is undefined even thought it should have a value because a json object is returned from the API?

Comment: @CamrinParnell - As long as we are making unit tests - there is no connection to backend. All data are stubbed / mocked and provided by spies. We are testing is our business logic corectly handle data. You must to mock JSON object that is returned by REST API. If you want test real data - you should looking for end to end tests.

Comment: So why would you bother testing a service using a unit test? Isn't it important to test that the response server returns data? Sorry I am finding this concept rather confusing, even after reading http://googletesting.blogspot.ca/2015/04/just-say-no-to-more-end-to-end-tests.html.

Comment: @CamrinParnell for unit tests I suggest to focus on spies - for example - if you call `User.loginUser` with some data is it pass to `User.login()`. Other tests with $resource just prooves that AngularJS works. We want to test business logic with unit tests. If you want test what is returned by backend - this is place for integratioin tests / end to end tests

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation.